# What are the differences between the English and French versions of Die2Nite?

Tags: die2nite, version-differences

As Die2Nite is originally a French game called Hordes, the English version was released a while after the French version. The result of this is that those of us who play the English version often get updates pushed to the servers months after the French receive them.

I'm interested in knowing what features and mechanics differ between these two versions of the game. Is there anywhere I can find an up-to-date list of these differences, or, barring that, could someone please make one and post it here?

Comment: tagged 'spoiler' because the devs treat it as such

Comment: Voting to close as too localized since the answer is constantly changing and the two will only continue to get more different over time.

Comment: @bwarner Agreed. Voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one main difference I've seen while perusing the hordes wikis and the public release notes is their season 2 feature:

> **Ghouls**, half infected citizens.
>
> You have a voracity gauge that fills up and to keep your sentience you must keep it below a red limit. You drop it by eating (human?) meat of any kind, and eating citizens alive nets you free hero days. Human meat also replenishes AP. You also get to stealthily enter and leave town and stay outside during the attack apparently. To balance, water is fatal, you must eat a citizen every day to survive and the risk.
>
> You can find out more at [the hordes.fr help pages.](http://www.hordes.fr/aide/les_goules)

Additionally, some more features have been added. Links lead to spoilers.

> - [Camping outside](http://www.hordes.fr/aide/camping_sauvage) - if you do survive, you get bonuses to searches
> - [Devasted cities](http://www.hordes.fr/aide/ville_devastee) - camping outside may let you outlive your fellow citizens. The town becomes completely useless in the process, however.
> - [Hermit](http://www.hordes.fr/aide/ermite) - higher chances to find food or water in the desert, which matters if you're on a 3+ day long expedition.
> - [Tamer](http://www.hordes.fr/aide/apprivoiseur) - you have a dog. The dog can carry items home for you. Put the dog on steroids and he'll even carry heavy objects.
> - [Seasons](http://www.hordes.fr/aide/saisons_et_classements) - each three months long, each with their own official town standings. Every town scores one point per citizen per day. Winners get, for the following season, a couple of perks (but no free hero days).

Answer (score 1):

The French version has five hero types instead of three.

Comment: Which hero types?